# Programmatically create product category and add thumbnail in woocommerce

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, terms

I'm trying to create product-(sub)categories on a WordPress installation. The (sub)categories part is no problem at all, but I can't seem to find a way to add the thumbnail image to the specific category.

In `wp-admin`, the field I want to fill asks for an attachment ID, so I tried uploading the image as attachment, without connecting it to a specific post. I then created my category, and tried the field names `product_cat_thumbnail_id` and `thumbnail_id` inside the `wp_insert_term()` function, and fill them with the attachment id. Just like the `wp-admin` function does, except `wp-admin` fills it with JavaScript after uploading, then saves it all when creating the category.

I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong, I'm missing something obvious, or that it's simply some kind of protected field that you are not allowed to fill.. (Which seems crazy to me)

Any ideas?

Comment: how do you use `wp_insert_term` ? there is now support for a field `thumbnail_id`, you have to add it on a second time with the woocommerce function `update_woocommerce_term_meta`. look in wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\admin\class-wc-admin-taxonomies.php

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I was able to get the term id, and use this to update the thumbnail_id meta. I'll answer my own question in a minute, with credits to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hereby my answer to my own post. I hope this is helpful to others too!

To create the category, I used an array with the data per category needed for the function `wp_insert_term`.

Then i looped trough that array,and used a `fetch_media` function that uploads the image found in the image-path given to that function, and returns an attachment ID.

I then call the `wp_insert_term` function, which i set as `$cid`, so that I can get the `term_id` value back from the returned array output.

With the returned `$cid['term_id']` and the `$thumb_id` fetched from the `fetch_media` function, I can use the `update_woocommerce_term_meta` function, and update my thumbnail with the uploaded attachment.

The basic `fetch_media` function I'm using can be found here:
http://nlb-creations.com/2012/09/26/how-to-programmatically-import-media-files-to-wordpress/

I altered it so that the post_id was not required, because obviously, my terms (categories) aren't posts.

```
$cats = array(
    array('thumb' => 'images/uploads/cat09.png','name' => 'Cat 9','description' => 'Cat 9 description','slug' => 'cat-9','parent' => 8),
    array('thumb' => 'images/uploads/cat10.png','name' => 'Cat 10','description' => 'Cat 10 description','slug' => 'cat-10','parent' => 8),
    array('thumb' => 'images/uploads/cat11.png','name' => 'Cat 11','description' => 'Cat 11 description','slug' => 'cat-11','parent' => 8),
);

foreach($cats as $data) {
    $thumb_id = fetch_media($data['thumb']);
    $cid = wp_insert_term(
        $data['name'], // the term 
        'product_cat', // the taxonomy
        array(
            'description'=> $data['description'],
            'slug' => $data['slug'],
            'parent' => $data['parent']
        )
    );

    if(!is_wp_error($cid)){
        $cat_id = isset( $cid['term_id'] ) ? $cid['term_id'] : 0;
        update_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat_id, 'thumbnail_id', absint( $thumb_id ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: since WooCommerce v3.6 `update_woocommerce_term_meta` is [deprecated](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-update_woocommerce_term_meta.html), use WordPress core function  [update_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_term_meta/) instead.